# Publish WinForm on ftp with subsequent updates

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ftp, clickonce

I've been trying for a while to find a reliable and straightforward way to implement auto-updating for my WinForm applications.

I've researched examples in which I ought to implement a new class and do the whole process manually. **This is not what I want to do**.

Instead, I want to use the VS publish to ftp option, as shown below.

[image]

I preselected all of the update options I want as shown below.

[image]

I get the following output:

```
2>------ Publish started: Project: MyApp, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
Connecting to 'ftp://ftp.mysite.com/'...
Publishing files...
Publish success.
Warning: Unable to view published application at ftp://ftp.sigmoidgroup.com/.
ftp://ftp.mysite.com/
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

When I log-in to my server, I can see the following files:

[image]

My question now is... how do I implement the installation for the client? Do I have to create a separate mini-app that downloads the files from the ftp (checks the latest version) or is this already pre-defined in VS?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl yes. Sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 0):

The auto-update should just work if you deploy to the same folder location. (If users have a shortcut to the manifest on the ftp site, ClickOnce handles the updating of files). I see you have different folders for different versions, you shouldn't need more than one unless users need to access older versions. See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d.aspx) for more ClickOnce info.